# Cannot deploy war to prod via jenkins

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins, deployment

Hello we have 2 environments QA/Prod with same configuration (F5 and firewall)
i am able to deploy to QA from Jenkins using deploy to container plugin, however with the same configuration, I am not able to deploy to Prod (tomcat6).  Exception:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy[E:\opt\jenkins\workspace\Deploy to Prod\newrecovery.war]


at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 328182350955272879</body></html>" instead of the expected "OK" message
```

Comment: Does the Production tomcat has user created and roles are assigned?

Comment: yes, the same user and password as QA under tomcat users config

Comment: This part of the error message `The requested URL was rejected. ` looks like the administration part of Tomcat is not installed?

Comment: by administration you mean tom-users, like admin, and gu and scirpt manager?

Comment: Found the problem, The F5 they were blocking it, they are going to add an exception to the IP of my server where jenkins is running from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, F5 was blocking the deployment, they are going to add an exception to the IP of my server where jenkins is running from –